# Android: SQLite database insertion successful yet with repetitive error messages

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, while-loop, populate

The code shown should take data from a text file and insert it into a database (currently only 1 table is being filled, the other insertion loops have been commented out).

The population of the pieceTable takes place inside the if statement inside the ManipulateDatabase constructor. At present, the database is filled (known because a select statement can retrieve data from it) yet the LogCat shows repeated errors in inserting various Strings to the table.

I have added LogCat output below but have had to use PasteBin to attach code due to character limitations in the post: http://pastebin.com/aR6kA3u8

Any suggestions of the source of the error would be greatly appreciated.

```
01-03 20:03:46.126: D/gralloc_goldfish(535): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-03 20:04:20.085: E/SQLiteDatabase(535): Error inserting isPlay=1 piece=A View from the Bridge
01-03 20:04:20.085: E/SQLiteDatabase(535): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
01-03 20:04:20.085: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_executeInsert(Native Method)
01-03 20:04:20.085: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:113)
01-03 20:04:20.085: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1718)
01-03 20:04:20.085: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1591)
01-03 20:04:20.085: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at com.lawson.englishlitrevision.ManipulateDatabase.<init>(ManipulateDatabase.java:576)
01-03 20:04:20.085: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at com.lawson.englishlitrevision.Novel.onCreate(Novel.java:22)
01-03 20:04:20.085: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-03 20:04:20.085: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-03 20:04:20.085: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
01-03 20:04:20.085: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
01-03 20:04:20.085: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-03 20:04:20.085: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
01-03 20:04:20.085: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-03 20:04:20.085: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-03 20:04:20.085: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-03 20:04:20.085: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 20:04:20.085: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-03 20:04:20.085: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-03 20:04:20.085: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-03 20:04:20.085: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-03 20:04:20.085: I/System.out(535): A View from the Bridge,1 THIS INSERTION SHOULD HAVE JUST FINISHED
01-03 20:04:20.115: E/SQLiteDatabase(535): Error inserting isPlay=1 piece=An Inspector Calls
01-03 20:04:20.115: E/SQLiteDatabase(535): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
01-03 20:04:20.115: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_executeInsert(Native Method)
01-03 20:04:20.115: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:113)
01-03 20:04:20.115: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1718)
01-03 20:04:20.115: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1591)
01-03 20:04:20.115: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at com.lawson.englishlitrevision.ManipulateDatabase.<init>(ManipulateDatabase.java:576)
01-03 20:04:20.115: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at com.lawson.englishlitrevision.Novel.onCreate(Novel.java:22)
01-03 20:04:20.115: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-03 20:04:20.115: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-03 20:04:20.115: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
01-03 20:04:20.115: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
01-03 20:04:20.115: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-03 20:04:20.115: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
01-03 20:04:20.115: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-03 20:04:20.115: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-03 20:04:20.115: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-03 20:04:20.115: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 20:04:20.115: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-03 20:04:20.115: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-03 20:04:20.115: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-03 20:04:20.115: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-03 20:04:20.115: I/System.out(535): An Inspector Calls,1 THIS INSERTION SHOULD HAVE JUST FINISHED
01-03 20:04:20.145: E/SQLiteDatabase(535): Error inserting isPlay=0 piece=Of Mice and Men
01-03 20:04:20.145: E/SQLiteDatabase(535): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
01-03 20:04:20.145: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_executeInsert(Native Method)
01-03 20:04:20.145: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:113)
01-03 20:04:20.145: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1718)
01-03 20:04:20.145: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1591)
01-03 20:04:20.145: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at com.lawson.englishlitrevision.ManipulateDatabase.<init>(ManipulateDatabase.java:576)
01-03 20:04:20.145: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at com.lawson.englishlitrevision.Novel.onCreate(Novel.java:22)
01-03 20:04:20.145: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-03 20:04:20.145: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-03 20:04:20.145: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
01-03 20:04:20.145: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
01-03 20:04:20.145: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-03 20:04:20.145: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
01-03 20:04:20.145: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-03 20:04:20.145: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-03 20:04:20.145: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-03 20:04:20.145: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 20:04:20.145: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-03 20:04:20.145: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-03 20:04:20.145: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-03 20:04:20.145: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-03 20:04:20.145: I/System.out(535): Of Mice and Men,0 THIS INSERTION SHOULD HAVE JUST FINISHED
01-03 20:04:20.186: E/SQLiteDatabase(535): Error inserting isPlay=0 piece=To Kill a Mockingbird
01-03 20:04:20.186: E/SQLiteDatabase(535): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
01-03 20:04:20.186: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_executeInsert(Native Method)
01-03 20:04:20.186: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:113)
01-03 20:04:20.186: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1718)
01-03 20:04:20.186: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1591)
01-03 20:04:20.186: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at com.lawson.englishlitrevision.ManipulateDatabase.<init>(ManipulateDatabase.java:576)
01-03 20:04:20.186: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at com.lawson.englishlitrevision.Novel.onCreate(Novel.java:22)
01-03 20:04:20.186: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
01-03 20:04:20.186: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-03 20:04:20.186: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
01-03 20:04:20.186: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
01-03 20:04:20.186: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
01-03 20:04:20.186: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
01-03 20:04:20.186: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-03 20:04:20.186: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-03 20:04:20.186: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
01-03 20:04:20.186: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 20:04:20.186: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-03 20:04:20.186: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-03 20:04:20.186: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-03 20:04:20.186: E/SQLiteDatabase(535):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-03 20:04:20.186: I/System.out(535): To Kill a Mockingbird,0 THIS INSERTION SHOULD HAVE JUST FINISHED
01-03 20:04:20.206: I/System.out(535): Of Mice and Men HAS JUST BEEN ADDED TO PIECE ARRAYLIST FETCHED FROM DB
01-03 20:04:20.206: I/System.out(535): To Kill a Mockingbird HAS JUST BEEN ADDED TO PIECE ARRAYLIST FETCHED FROM DB
01-03 20:04:20.246: D/dalvikvm(535): GC_CONCURRENT freed 228K, 4% free 9288K/9607K, paused 5ms+3ms
```

Comment: it would be helpful to have your schema code and the insertion/constructor code as well.

Comment: I was forced to use PasteBin to add the code of the DBM class as the character limit was restrictive. The link is here: http://pastebin.com/aR6kA3u8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking around line 597 it looks like you are creating a `ContentValues` object with two strings. But your schema for that table says you have two columns, once text another integer.

That's where I would start looking.

Comment: Thank you very much, I believe this was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `piece` column is defined with a `PRIMARY KEY` constraint which enforces uniqueness. You will need to use the `insertWithOnConflict()` method to specify a custom `ON CONFLICT` clause if you want to avoid these exceptions.